# Finding pattern in a matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix

I have a 8 x n matrix, for instance

```
set.seed(12345)
m <- matrix(sample(1:50, 800, replace=T), ncol=8)
head(m)

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8]
[1,]   37   15   30    3    4   11   35   31
[2,]   44   31   45   30   24   39    1   18
[3,]   39   49    7   36   14   43   26   24
[4,]   45   31   26   33   12   47   37   15
[5,]   23   27   34   29   30   34   17    4
[6,]    9   46   39   34    8   43   42   37
```

I would like to find a certain pattern in the matrix, for instance I would like to know where I can find a 37, followed in the next line by a 10 and a 29 and the line after by a 42

This happens, for instance, in lines 57:59 of the above matrix

```
m[57:59,]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8]
[1,]  *37   35    1   30   47    9   12   39
[2,]    5   22  *10  *29   13    5   17   36
[3,]   22   43    6    2   27   35  *42   50
```

A (probably inefficient) solution is to get all the lines containing 37 with

```
sapply(1:nrow(m), function(x){37 %in% m[x,]})
```

And then use a few loops to test the other conditions.

How could I write an efficient function to do this, that can be generalized to any user-given pattern (not necessarily over 3 lines, with possible "holes", with variable number of values in each line etc).?

EDIT: to answer various comments

- I need to find the EXACT pattern
- The order in the same row does not matter (if it makes things easier values can be ordered in each row)
- The lines have to be adjacent.
- I want to get the (starting) position of all the pattern returned (i.e., if the pattern is present multiple times in the matrix I want multiple return values).
- The user would enter the pattern via a GUI, I have yet to decide how. For instance, to search for the above pattern he may write something like

`37;10,29;42`

Where `;` represents a new line and `,` separates values on the same line.
Similarly we may look for

```
50,51;;75;80,81
```

Meaning 50 and 51 in line n, 75 in line n+2, and 80 and 81 in line n+3

Comment: A quick possible optimization would be to truncate the matrix by finding the first value (37 in your example) and the last value (42 in your example).

Comment: @Arun: yes, I am looking for the **exact** pattern

Comment: Does the order of `10` and `29` matter?

Comment: I think the question becomes: what should the user input be? How?

Comment: And I suppose you would like the 3 lines containing this input as output? Do you want all the matching patterns returned?

Comment: Added details in the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a generalized function:

```
PatternMatcher <- function(data, pattern, idx = NULL) {
  p <- unlist(pattern[1])
  if(is.null(idx)){
    p <- unlist(pattern[length(pattern)])
    PatternMatcher(data, rev(pattern)[-1], 
                   idx = Filter(function(n) all(p %in% intersect(data[n, ], p)),
                                1:nrow(data)))
  } else if(length(pattern) > 1) {
    PatternMatcher(data, pattern[-1], 
                   idx = Filter(function(n) all(p %in% intersect(data[n, ], p)), 
                                idx - 1))
  } else
    Filter(function(n) all(p %in% intersect(data[n, ], p)), idx - 1)
}
```

This is a recursive function which is reducing `pattern` in every iteration and checks only rows that go right after ones identified in the previous iteration. List structure allows passing the pattern in a convenient way:

```
PatternMatcher(m, list(37, list(10, 29), 42))
# [1] 57
PatternMatcher(m, list(list(45, 24, 1), 7, list(45, 31), 4))
# [1] 2
PatternMatcher(m, list(1,3))
# [1] 47 48 93
```

**Edit:** The idea of the function above seems fine: check all rows for the vector `pattern[[1]]` and get indices `r1`, then check rows `r1+1` for `pattern[[2]]` and get `r2`, etc. But it takes really much time at the first step when going through all rows. Of course, every step would take much time with e.g. `m <- matrix(sample(1:10, 800, replace=T), ncol=8)`, i.e. when there is not much of a change in indices `r1`, `r2`, ... So here is another approach, here `PatternMatcher` looks very similar, but there is another function `matchRow` for finding rows that have all elements of `vector`.

```
matchRow <- function(data, vector, idx = NULL){
  if(is.null(idx)){
    matchRow(data, vector[-1], 
             as.numeric(unique(rownames(which(data == vector[1], arr.ind = TRUE)))))
  } else if(length(vector) > 0) {
    matchRow(data, vector[-1], 
             as.numeric(unique(rownames(which(data[idx, , drop = FALSE] == vector[1], arr.ind = TRUE)))))
  } else idx
}
PatternMatcher <- function(data, pattern, idx = NULL) {
  p <- pattern[[1]]
  if(is.null(idx)){
    rownames(data) <- 1:nrow(data)
    p <- pattern[[length(pattern)]]
    PatternMatcher(data, rev(pattern)[-1], idx = matchRow(data, p))
  } else if(length(pattern) > 1) {
    PatternMatcher(data, pattern[-1], idx = matchRow(data, p, idx - 1))
  } else
    matchRow(data, p, idx - 1)
}
```

Comparison with the previous function:

```
library(rbenchmark)
bigM <- matrix(sample(1:50, 800000, replace=T), ncol=8)
benchmark(PatternMatcher(bigM, list(37, c(10, 29), 42)), 
          PatternMatcher(bigM, list(1, 3)), 
          OldPatternMatcher(bigM, list(37, list(10, 29), 42)), 
          OldPatternMatcher(bigM, list(1, 3)), 
          replications = 10,
          columns = c("test", "elapsed"))
#                                                  test elapsed
# 4                 OldPatternMatcher(bigM, list(1, 3))   61.14
# 3 OldPatternMatcher(bigM, list(37, list(10, 29), 42))   63.28
# 2                    PatternMatcher(bigM, list(1, 3))    1.58
# 1       PatternMatcher(bigM, list(37, c(10, 29), 42))    2.02

verybigM1 <- matrix(sample(1:40, 8000000, replace=T), ncol=20)
verybigM2 <- matrix(sample(1:140, 8000000, replace=T), ncol=20)
benchmark(PatternMatcher(verybigM1, list(37, c(10, 29), 42)), 
          PatternMatcher(verybigM2, list(37, c(10, 29), 42)), 
          find.combo(verybigM1, convert.gui.input("37;10,29;42")),
          find.combo(verybigM2, convert.gui.input("37;10,29;42")),          
          replications = 20,
          columns = c("test", "elapsed"))
#                                                      test elapsed
# 3 find.combo(verybigM1, convert.gui.input("37;10,29;42"))   17.55
# 4 find.combo(verybigM2, convert.gui.input("37;10,29;42"))   18.72
# 1      PatternMatcher(verybigM1, list(37, c(10, 29), 42))   15.84
# 2      PatternMatcher(verybigM2, list(37, c(10, 29), 42))   19.62
```

Also now the `pattern` argument should be like `list(37, c(10, 29), 42)` instead of `list(37, list(10, 29), 42)`. And finally:

```
fastPattern <- function(data, pattern)
  PatternMatcher(data, lapply(strsplit(pattern, ";")[[1]], 
                    function(i) as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(i, split = ",")))))
fastPattern(m, "37;10,29;42")
# [1] 57
fastPattern(m, "37;;42")
# [1] 57  4
fastPattern(m, "37;;;42")
# [1] 33 56 77
```

Comment: This is very interesting, I need some time to study it in detail, but I like the idea

Comment: @nico, I added a few details. Still making it more efficient, the first step usually takes most of the time.

Comment: @flodel, sure, was doing that when caught `integer(0)`. But now it seems that `find.combo(bigM, pattern.df)` and `PatternMatcher(bigM, list(37, c(10, 29), 42))` do not match.

Comment: You need to sort your output.

Comment: @flodel, just found that the problem was that I was still using `find.combo(m, pattern.df)` instead of `find.combo(m, convert.gui.input("37;10,29;42"))`

Answer (score 5):

This reads easily and is hopefully generalizable enough for you:

```
has.37 <- rowSums(m == 37) > 0
has.10 <- rowSums(m == 10) > 0
has.29 <- rowSums(m == 29) > 0
has.42 <- rowSums(m == 42) > 0

lag <- function(x, lag) c(tail(x, -lag), c(rep(FALSE, lag)))

which(has.37 & lag(has.10, 1) & lag(has.29, 1) & lag(has.42, 2))
# [1] 57
```

---

**Edit:** here is a generalization that can use positive and negative lags:

```
find.combo <- function(m, pattern.df) {

   lag <- function(v, i) {
      if (i == 0) v else
      if (i > 0)  c(tail(v, -i), c(rep(FALSE, i))) else
      c(rep(FALSE, -i), head(v, i))
   }

   find.one <- function(x, i) lag(rowSums(m == x) > 0, i)
   matches  <- mapply(find.one, pattern.df$value, pattern.df$lag)
   which(rowSums(matches) == ncol(matches))

}
```

Tested here:

```
pattern.df <- data.frame(value = c(40, 37, 10, 29, 42),
                         lag   = c(-1,  0,  1,  1,  2))

find.combo(m, pattern.df)
# [1] 57
```

---

**Edit2:** following the OP's edit regarding a GUI input, here is a function that transforms the GUI input into the `pattern.df` my `find.combo` function expects:

```
convert.gui.input <- function(string) {
   rows   <- strsplit(string, ";")[[1]]
   values <- strsplit(rows,   ",")
   data.frame(value = as.numeric(unlist(values)),
              lag = rep(seq_along(values), sapply(values, length)) - 1)
}
```

Tested here:

```
find.combo(m, convert.gui.input("37;10,29;42"))
# [1] 57
```

Answer (score 3):

Since you have integer you can convert your matrix to a string and  use regular expression

```
ss <- paste(apply(m,1,function(x) paste(x,collapse='-')),collapse=' ')
## some funny regular expression
pattern <- '[^ \t]+[ \t]{1}[^ \t]+10[^ \t]+29[^ \t]+[ \t]{1}[^ \t]+42'
regmatches(ss,regexpr(pattern ,text=ss))
[1] "37-35-1-30-47-9-12-39 5-22-10-29-13-5-17-36 22-43-6-2-27-35-42"

 regexpr(pattern ,text=ss)
[1] 1279
attr(,"match.length")
[1] 62
attr(,"useBytes")
[1] TRUE
```

To see it in action take a look at [this](http://regexpal.com/?flags=gm&regex=37%5B%5E%20%5Ct%5D%2b%5B%20%5Ct%5D%7B1%7D%5B%5E%20%5Ct%5D%2b10%5B%5E%20%5Ct%5D%2b29%5B%5E%20%5Ct%5D%2b%5B%20%5Ct%5D%7B1%7D%5B%5E%20%5Ct%5D%2b42&input=%20%2237-15-30-3-4-11-35-31%2044-31-45-30-24-39-1-18%2039-49-7-36-14-43-26-24%2045-31-26-33-12-47-37-15%2023-27-34-29-30-34-17-4%209-46-39-34-8-43-42-37%2017-32-5-11-43-4-45-7%2026-44-4-12-12-32-43-39%2037-13-28-23-40-20-23-43%2050-11-33-18-4-38-24-18%202-31-15-21-28-37-26-18%208-20-35-22-36-19-9-47%2037-38-19-48-3-17-45-32%201-19-14-12-2-34-11-17%2020-40-48-19-38-17-32-26%2024-46-22-45-39-35-3-22%2020-50-17-27-27-11-19-35%2021-30-27-30-20-13-31-46%209-1-32-13-24-7-48-9%2048-17-9-44-7-40-11-14%2023-28-6-16-42-39-9-18%2017-26-6-34-14-10-44-2%2049-5-5-31-10-45-24-2%2036-35-27-21-13-30-12-5%2033-36-45-21-20-23-46-31%2020-41-36-49-43-15-49-1%2035-48-46-16-50-16-48-22%2028-10-22-1-16-29-28-5%2012-14-24-9-14-47-50-26%2025-39-30-12-32-41-18-27%2040-2-16-20-32-22-19-38%201-34-29-43-3-18-22-32%2010-41-24-37-38-26-15-32%2035-34-35-34-16-33-4-43%2019-48-37-6-3-35-4-48%2019-44-26-3-29-42-22-32%2044-35-50-49-1-6-50-38%2046-10-46-37-44-46-6-6%2031-5-24-25-27-13-12-20%207-41-20-45-6-21-12-46%2040-27-47-29-41-14-33-23%2022-35-48-35-41-17-26-4%2047-11-46-46-1-13-37-48%2039-32-40-42-35-27-16-48%2013-8-32-26-23-36-43-35%2017-48-34-32-46-27-26-3%204-50-47-40-20-1-35-36%203-25-27-48-1-32-48-17%203-46-17-3-49-31-1-38%2032-19-40-38-49-39-27-48%2049-42-7-35-38-44-42-11%2042-28-48-32-21-23-17-38%2016-40-2-50-21-26-35-44%2011-18-13-32-42-45-31-23%2037-11-44-33-26-19-33-2%2025-40-43-37-35-13-48-14%2037-35-1-30-47-9-12-39%205-22-10-29-13-5-17-36%2022-43-6-2-27-35-42-50%2012-31-24-40-5-18-8-1%2040-38-48-10-27-4-47-16%2013-30-42-9-47-4-5-13%2050-43-41-25-11-29-35-23%2038-41-46-13-44-35-49-27%2049-20-36-18-29-10-32-33%2011-25-5-36-20-14-22-47%2048-50-6-44-31-48-41-15%208-9-40-13-19-26-14-41%2031-42-50-40-41-38-33-35%2048-20-35-29-15-12-30-10%2035-49-8-27-16-32-33-23%2026-10-16-40-21-32-2-43%2019-38-8-47-39-28-4-41%2017-16-50-32-33-13-50-16%203-19-38-33-14-13-47-50%2031-38-20-22-16-24-10-20%2049-36-28-22-37-42-35-6%2033-47-2-49-39-12-17-1%2026-40-17-16-30-39-34-17%208-42-43-23-6-27-4-42%2044-9-7-36-13-17-50-40%2026-21-40-41-14-39-7-19%201-10-5-16-15-12-19-35%201-13-1-34-27-17-43-31%208-49-14-40-20-22-42-28%2016-41-21-44-33-35-34-43%2042-18-4-31-8-33-36-18%2026-47-40-10-44-37-45-16%2041-9-26-46-23-9-24-31%204-8-26-2-45-3-36-17%2047-38-36-40-39-29-23-31%2041-45-42-43-41-6-46-13%204-16-4-41-50-1-6-37%2031-16-17-9-30-39-3-1%2036-50-41-17-24-14-36-32%2026-1-15-10-17-35-44-44%2037-14-41-17-36-12-1-25%2038-40-11-20-38-49-38-25%205-13-28-26-39-34-40-5%2020-23-1-7-44-40-25-20%22) .

**Edit  Consutruct the pattern dynamically**

```
searchep <- '37;10,29;42'       #string given by the user
str1 <- '[^ \t]+[ \t]{1}[^ \t]+' 
str2 <- '[^ \t]'
hh <- gsub(';',str1,searchep)
pattern <- gsub(',',str2,hh)
pattern
[1] "37[^ \t]+[ \t]{1}[^ \t]+10[^ \t]29[^ \t]+[ \t]{1}[^ \t]+42"

test for searchep <- '37;10,29;;40'  ## we skip a line here 

pattern
[1] "37[^ \t]+[ \t]{1}[^ \t]+10[^ \t]29[^ \t]+[ \t]{1}[^ \t]+[^ \t]+[ \t]{1}[^ \t]+40"
regmatches(ss,regexpr(pattern ,text=ss))
"37-35-1-30-47-9-12-39 5-22-10-29-13-5-17-36 22-43-6-2-27-35-42-50 12-31-24-40"
```

**Edit2 Test proformances**

```
matrix.pattern <- function(searchep='37;10,29;42' ){
 str1 <- '[^ \t]+[ \t]{1}[^ \t]+' 
 str2 <- '[^ \t]+'
 hh <- gsub(';',str1,searchep)
 pattern <- gsub(',',str2,hh)
 res <- regmatches(ss,regexpr(pattern ,text=ss))
}

system.time({ss <- paste(apply(bigM,1,function(x) paste(x,collapse='-')),collapse=' ')
             matrix.pattern('37;10,29;42')})
   user  system elapsed 
   2.36    0.01    2.40
```

If the big matrix don't change , the step of transformation to a string id done only once and performance are very good.

```
system.time(matrix.pattern('37;10,29;42'))
   user  system elapsed 
   0.71    0.02    0.72
```

Comment: +1 for thinking outside the box, but I think this may be a bit complex to generalize and maintain.

Comment: no it is easy to generalize  I will show it after you have  updated! but to maintain maybe yes it is regular expression!

Comment: @nico I update my answer with a link, maybe you can be inspired for your application.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it will help someone, but as for input, I was thinking of the following:

```
PatternMatcher <- function(data, ...) {
  Selecting procedure here.
}

PatternMatcher(m, c(1, 37, 2, 10, 2, 29, 4, 42))
```

The second part fed to the function consists of, in order, the line where it should start, followed by the value, and then the second line, and the second value. You could now also say for instance the 8th line after the initial line with the value 50.

You could even extend this to ask for specific X, Y coordinates per value (so 3 items passed to the function per value).

Comment: `list(37, c(10, 29), 42)` seems more natural to me.

Comment: That is a more specific case, if you want to generalize this to any pattern with any line then you cant shorten it like that.

Comment: Why doesn't the list generalise?  If you want to miss out lines, you can just pass an empty vector.  `list(37, c(10, 29), c(), 42)`

Comment: because it is like this: all the odd index numbers (1,3,5 etc) are the numbers indicating which row to search after the first one, all the even index numbers are the values to search for.

Comment: In your way, you don't allow any options for which row to search (that is, unless you want to put in 10 times the c() if you are interested in the 11th row.

Comment: Mixing two different concepts (row to search and values to search for) with alternating values would be hard to debug and isn't a very Rish way to do things.  The list gives you everything you want in a single natural structure.  And you can just do `pattern[[11]] <- c(1,2,3)` to specify that the 11th row contains numbers to look for.

Answer (score 2):

`Edit:` Now, I've added a more generalised function:

Here's one solution that gives all possible combinations: I obtain all the positions of all four numbers, then use `expand.grid` to obtain all position combinations and then `filter the meaningless` ones by checking if each row of the matrix is equal to the corresponding row of the sorted matrix.

```
set.seed(12345)
m <- matrix(sample(1:50, 800, replace=T), ncol=8)
head(m)
get_grid <- function(in_mat, vec_num) {
    v.idx <- sapply(vec_num, function(idx) {
        which(apply(in_mat, 1, function(x) any(x == idx)))
    })
    out <- as.matrix(expand.grid(v.idx))
    colnames(out) <- NULL
    out
}

out <- get_grid(m, c(37, 10, 29, 42))
out.s <- t(apply(out, 1, sort))

idx <- rowSums(out == out.s)
out.f <- out[idx==4, ]

> dim(out.f)
[1] 2946    4

> head(out.f)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1   22   28   36
[2,]    4   22   28   36
[3,]    6   22   28   36
[4,]    9   22   28   36
[5,]   11   22   28   36
[6,]   13   22   28   36
```

These are the row indices of the occurrence of numbers in that order (37, 10, 29, 42).

From this, you can check any combination you wish. For example, the combination you had asked for can be accomplished by:

```
cont.idx <- apply(out.f, 1, function(x) x[1] == x[2]-1 & x[2] == x[4]-1)
> out.f[cont.idx,]
[1] 57 58 58 59
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way using `sapply`:

```
which(sapply(seq(nrow(m)-2),
             function(x)
               isTRUE(37 %in% m[x,] & 
                      which(10 == m[x+1,]) < which(29 == m[x+1,]) & 
                      42 %in% m[x+2,])))
```

The result contains all row number where the sequence starts:

```
[1] 57
```

Comment: Maybe try to use my answer to combine our two functions to give a general solution?

Answer (score 0):

as.data.frame(your_matrix) %>%
    dplyr::filter_all(dplyr::any_vars(stringr::str_detect(., pattern = "your-pattern")))