# Is there an R function to find the row indices that contain a specific pattern?

Tags: r

Currently I am working with data that shows a sequence of activities, from these sequences I want to extract the rows that follow a specific pattern.

Some example sequences:

```
set.seed(12345)
m <- matrix(sample(1:10, 800, replace=T), ncol=8)
m[sample(1:100, 20, replace=T), 8] <- NA #sequences have variable lengths
head(m)

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8]
[1,]    4    2    3    1    1    2    4    4
[2,]    5    4    5    3    3    4    1    2
[3,]    4    5    1    4    2    5    3    3
[4,]    5    4    3    4    2    5    4   NA
[5,]    3    3    4    3    3    4    2    1
[6,]    1    5    4    4    1    5    5    4
```

One solution is to use two for loops to check each row for the possible pattern, however i've experienced that the calculation times grow fast when matrices get larger. I've tried the example code below for a pattern of size 3 where activity 1 is followed by activity 2 and activity 3:

```
pattern <- list(1,2,3)
g <- list()

for (i in 1:NROW(m)){
  if (any(m[i,]==pattern[1], na.rm = TRUE) & any(m[i,]==pattern[2], na.rm = TRUE) & any(m[i,]==pattern[3], na.rm = TRUE)){
    for(ii in 1:(NCOL(m)-2)){
     if((m[i,ii]==pattern[1]) & (m[i,ii+1]==pattern[2]) & (m[i,ii+2]==pattern[3])){
       g <- append(g,i)
     } 
    }
  }
}
```

This loop seems to work, as it provides a list with the indices of the rows that match the pattern (row 28, 32 and 99). Howerver, this method is not scalable for longer/shorter patterns. Also, in this example the pattern "1 -> 2 -> 3" was inspected, but I would also like the possibility to inspect for patterns like "1 -> (2, 4 or 5) -> 3".

I was hoping to write a function similar to the accepted answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14154952/finding-pattern-in-a-matrix-in-r), where the input requires a matrix and a pattern displayed as a list. However my R knowledge is limited and I could use some help.

Comment: grepl( 15.8 , mtcars$mpg)

Comment: What is the pattern you are matching in the example?

Comment: classic regex or `grepl` use-case - check the help - maybe a helper column where you concatenate (i.e. `paste`) the values into a single column would make grepping easier as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can start by creating a vector that collapses each row of the matrix into a single string (in this case, separated by a space). Then we can quite easily `grep` it.

```
mm<-apply(m,1,paste,collapse=" ")
grep("1 2 3", mm)
integer(0)
grep("1 [245] 3", mm)
[1] 14 83
```

The first grep line gives your simple search (which has zero results).
The second grep line shows how you can search for more complicated patterns - this will search for your second example, of 1 -> 2, 4 or 5 -> 3.

Note that `grep` will give you the indices for the rows that match your pattern. Alternatively, `grepl` will give you a logical vector the same length as `m`, where TRUE indicates a match.